# Ajax call not triggering

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax

I want to fetch the employee details for autocomplete
below is my JS code, using break point I could confirm its entering the else condition,
but the ajax call is not being hit.

```
$("#EmpName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                if (request.term.length <= 1) {
                }
                else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/EmployeeController/GetEmployeeList",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: request,
                        success: function (data) {
                            var rows = new Array(data.length);
                            var count = -1;
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                response($.map(data, function (Label, Value) {
                                    count++;
                                    return {
                                        label: data[count].Label,
                                        value: data[count].Label
                                    };
                                }))
                            }
                            else {
                                response($.map(request, function (Label, Value) {
                                    return {
                                        label: "No result found",
                                        value: ""
                                    };
                                }))
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        });
```

and below is my code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetEmployeeList")]
public IActionResult GetEmployeeList(string term)
{
     //Create an object for  GetEmployeeList method
     return Json(ServiceLocator.Resolve<EmployeeService>().GetEmployeeList(term));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you put a try catch wrap into your ajax function ? check the exact error come from ?

Comment: check the network tab in developers tools, the request is likely being made but erroring out. You should use an error or `.catch()` callback to check

Comment: try to replace your `dataType` to `application/json`

Comment: Any chance to share some info of how your routing is set up? It is hard giving a good answer without knowing more about your setup or the potential errors being thrown. Does the network tab give you anymore information, do you have an error in your console?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling to EmployeeController (I'm hazarding a guess that you're using a framework like MVC with standard routing) shouldn't this be `url: "/Employee/GetEmployeeList"` instead of `url: "/EmployeeController/GetEmployeeList"` ?